# Notepad++ not detect .js file as javascript code

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I am writing javascript code using notepad++. I found this problem and i don't know how to solve it.

When i open/create a new javascript file, i have to set the language to Javascript so the display will be changed. 
Here's the example.
[image: i wrote a line "testing script"]

i wrote a line "testing script"

[image: And then i made it as a comment line, but the font color is still black.]

And then i made it as a comment line, but the font color is still black. The comment should written in green color.

[image]

I need to change the language to Javascript so it could be read as a javascript code and i could use the shortcut, just like ctrl+q to comment a line.

I don't why this is happened. But it just happened after i update notepad++. Can anyone help. This also happened when i open existing javascript code.

Comment: I haven't used notepad++ in a while, but does putting it in a script tag fix the issue?

Comment: @Ageonix - putting a script tag inside a JS script file would break it. Notepad++ is supposed to default the language based on the file extension - this works fine on the older version I have here.

Comment: Maybe asking the same question in the Notepad++ website's community forum would help.

Comment: meh. probably a bug or file-update conflict during upgrading. i would just wait until the next version to see if it fixes itself. or re-install if you're very concerned about it.

Comment: @dandavis  i already reinstall it, and it's not changed.  I also already downgraded it, and it didn't help. i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the newer version of notepad++ but the comment function is working great. just to sure try saving it first with the js extension and then try to comment the line it. hope it works for you!